# Twitter & YouTube Zoomed in iOS 7

Tags: xcode, ios7

Before iOS 7 was released in my iPhone application I had added Facebook, Twitter and YouTube in my application. Now since after the release of iOS 7, the Facebook page fits the screen but Twitter and YouTube are zoomed in. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of iOS 7.0.3 update this issue has been resolved.